# How to put div block into right screen area using css?

Tags: css, html

I created the simple web page layout that includes : header, left, right and footer div blocks.

This is the html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div class="header">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="article">
                <p>Article 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article">
                <p>Article 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article">
                <p>Article 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the css style :

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.header {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.left {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 1000px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.article {
    margin: 50px;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The web page looks like this:
[image]

But when i try to add the left block like on the picture it looks uncorrect. I use this css code for that:

```
.right {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: right;
}
```

**DEMO on jsFiddle**  - http://jsfiddle.net/khbTg/

How can I to put Left div block in the yellow area like on the picture? Thank you for any help.

Comment: please create a jsfiddle

Comment: @Adsy [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/VEINHORN/NAZy5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to float `.right` to the right. If you can change your markup to:

```
<div class="header">#header</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="nav">#nav</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="article">#article</div>
        <div class="article">#article</div>
        <div class="article">#article</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">#footer</div>
```

You would then want to add the styles:

```
.container { clear: both; }

.content { width: 80%; }

.right { 
    width: 20%;
    float: right; 
 }

.content, .right {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDNsA/1/. I added `.container` to help clear things, as you don't want to float around `.header` or `.footer`. Remember to avoid putting a `margin`, `padding` or `border` on `.right` or `.content`.

Comment: thank you but i would like to add articles and some moduls into right sidebar in the fiture. When i try to add another articles or some div blocks into container it looks bad. [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VEINHORN/cn47e/)

Comment: @veinhorn if you know the widths of things, then you would put the articles in another wrapper `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/cn47e/1/.

Answer (score 2):

Would you not need to put:

```
.left {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle then the community can attempt to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a float, the floated element is removed from document flow and 'floated' - following elements then flow *around* the floated element. To use a right float the way you wish, the right-floated element `.right` needs to appear in the DOM **before** the left element.

Alternatively, float your `.left` element left, and float your `.right` element left also - then they will layout correctly.

Don't forget to clear the floats afterwards :)

As a side-alternative, you could set `.left` and `.right` to `display: inline-block;` and this would solve your problem without floats and clears. You do need to then either (a) set font-size to 0 for the parent element to avoid the whitespace issue, or (b) comment out the whitespace between `.left` and `.right`. Google it if interested.

Answer (score 2):

I make a a demo file how can you make a simple page layout:

Enjoy it [PAGE LAYOUT EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/IVoneg/1/edit)

CSS:

```
header {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

article {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

sidebar {
  width: 90px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid yellow; 
  float: left;
}

footer {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: thank you, maybe you know how to add some blocks into article block? when i try to add some items it looks incorrectly. [reference](http://jsbin.com/IVoneg/8/edit) I would like to add items in a column.

Comment: @veinhorn - Check this [Demo](http://jsbin.com/UZUWEqE/1/edit) out! :-) - EDIT:  Sorry it was broken the link now its the correct

Comment: when i try to add more sections they cover footer maybe you know how can i to correct this trouble?:)[ref](http://jsbin.com/IVoneg/12/edit)

Comment: @veinhorn - You wan't sections on footer?

Comment: @veinhorn - [Demo](http://jsbin.com/IVoneg/14/edit) - change in CSS:  article: `height: auto;`